# QT how to include a header and cpp file

Tags: c++, qt, linker-errors, unresolved-external

I have a qt project that is setup like this

headers

```
mainwindow.h
```

source

```
main.cpp
mainwindow.cpp
```

in the mainwindow.h

```
just some function prototypes no includes
```

in the mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
some code
```

in the main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
```

This seems to work and is how the qt IDE setup the program

Now I wanted to add a separate .h and .cpp program for some functions

animationfunctions.h

```
#ifndef ANIMATIONFUNCTIONS_H
#define ANIMATIONFUNCTIONS_H

QPropertyAnimation* animationbuttonleft(QPushButton* guiitem, QString location, int startposition);

#endif // ANIMATIONFUNCTIONS_H
```

animationfunctions.cpp

```
#include "animationfunctions.h"

QPropertyAnimation* animationbuttonleft(QPushButton* guiitem, QString location, int startposition)
{
//
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "animationfunctions.h"
```

I thought this would work but it did not. I tried a lot of different include combinations, but I always get a lnk 2019 error with unresolved external symbol of the QPropertyAnimation* animationbuttonleft

I am wondering how I should set this up?

here is the relevant part of my .pro file

```
SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp \
    animationfunctions.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h \
    xcash_wallet_2.rc \
    animationfunctions.h
```

Thanks

Comment: Excuse me. The codes after `SOURCES +=`  or  `HEADERS +=`  in .pro file, why not in a line?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out from another stack overflow that you just have to clean your project and then run qmake from the build tab.

Comment: If that's the case mark your question as a duplicate.